# Is there a simpler way in python

Tags: python, python-re

I did the following to get from P13 to {P}{13}

```
import re

txt  = "P13"
x = re.search("[A-T]", txt )
y = re.split("[A-T]", txt )
txt  = "{" + x.group() + "}" + "{" + y[1] + "}"
```

It is working and gives what I want. But I'm wondering if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try regex replace

```
out = re.sub('([A-T]+)(\d+)', r'{\1}{\2}', txt)
```

```
$ print(out)

{P}{13}
```

Explanation:

- 1st Capturing Group `([A-T]+)`

  Match a single character present in the list `[A-T]` one and unlimited times
- 2nd Capturing Group `(\d+)`

  `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to `[0-9]`) and `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times

Comment: Would depend on if the OP expects one or more of `[A-T]`. Nice one-liner though.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Yes, it depends on what the input pattern is.